Could we use loss function in filter-based framework
As we all know, in optimization-based lidar-inertial-odometry(lio) framework, we usually use loss function to inhibit big residuals, which often caused by outlier measurements.
My question is, in filter-based lio framework,
Q1: Could we use loss function to weight residual ?
Q2: In optimization-based framework, like ceres-solver, it uses LLT to decompose measurement covariance, converting residual mahalanobis-distance to residual 2-norm. $\Sigma = L* L^T$, $r^T * \Sigma^{-1}* r = ||L^{-1}*r||_2$. In filter-based framework, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Kalman_filter#Discrete-time_predict_and_update_equations,  we use measurement noise $Q$ to calculate residual covariance $S$ and then use it to calculate kalman gain weight matrix $K$, finally use $K$ to weight prior distribution and posteriorse distribution. I think we could not to do the same thing, LLT decompose measurement covariance and weight residual like in optimization-based framework, right? Because we have done it in matrix $S$.
Thanks for your help sincerely!
Best regards

I think Robust Kalman Filters are what you are looking for. See "Robust Kalman Filter Based on a Generalized Maximum-Likelihood-Type Estimator" by Gandhi and Mili.

Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!
